# How does "sizeof" determine the size of an array?

Tags: arrays, c, sizeof

How does C find the size of an array at runtime? Where is the information about the array size or bounds stored ?

Answer (score 88, accepted):

`sizeof(array)` is implemented entirely by the C compiler. By the time the program gets linked, what looks like a `sizeof()` call to you has been converted into a constant.

Example: when you compile this C code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a[33];
    printf("%d\n", sizeof(a));
}
```

you get

```
    .file   "sz.c"
    .section        .rodata
.LC0:
    .string "%d\n"
    .text
.globl main
    .type   main, @function
main:
    leal    4(%esp), %ecx
    andl    $-16, %esp
    pushl   -4(%ecx)
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp, %ebp
    pushl   %ecx
    subl    $164, %esp
    movl    $132, 4(%esp)
    movl    $.LC0, (%esp)
    call    printf
    addl    $164, %esp
    popl    %ecx
    popl    %ebp
    leal    -4(%ecx), %esp
    ret
    .size   main, .-main
    .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.1.2 (Gentoo 4.1.2 p1.1)"
    .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

The `$132` in the middle is the size of the array, 132 = 4 * 33. Notice that there's no `call sizeof` instruction - unlike `printf`, which is a real function.

Comment: This answer is correct for fixed-size arrays, but is wrong for [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) which exist since C99.

Answer (score 25):

sizeof is pure compile time in C++ and C prior to C99. Starting with C99 there are variable length arrays:

```
// returns n + 3
int f(int n) {
    char v[n + 3];

    // not purely a compile time construct anymore
    return sizeof v;
}
```

That will evaluate the `sizeof` operand, because `n` is not yet known at compile time. That *only* applies to variable length arrays: Other operands or types still make sizeof compute at compile time. In particular, arrays with dimensions known at compile time are still handled like in C++ and C89. As a consequence, the value returned by `sizeof` is not a compile time constant (constant expression) anymore. You can't use it where such a value is required - for example when initializing static variables, unless a compiler specific extension allows it (the C Standard allows an implementation to have extensions to what it treats as constant).

Comment: Good that you mention C99 VLAs.  However, your answer should emphasize that even in C99, fixed size arrays have their size computed at compile time -- it is only VLAs that have their size computed at runtime.  And maybe, as a consequence, you can't always use 'sizeof(array)' as a constant in C99.

Comment: ok, bed time for me now. later i will wake up and scream about all those typos in my answers :p

Comment: +1 for distinguishing between compile-time and non-compile-time evaulations of `sizeof` in C99, but how is the length of a variable-length-array actually computed? Is it stored in an array descriptor or something?

Answer (score 15):

`sizeof()` will only work for a fixed size array (which can be static, stack based or in a struct).

If you apply it to an array created with `malloc` (or new in C++) you will always get the size of a pointer.

And yes, this is based on compile time information.

Comment: fixed size arrays are not necessarily stack based.  C has no new operator.

Comment: You've forgotten about C99 VLA - variable-length arrays.

Comment: "Array" has a quite specific meaning in C type system. If you have an _array_ (not a pointer), `sizeof` should work, even if the array is in memory allocated with `malloc` (possible via using pointer to array instead of pointer to element).

Answer (score 10):

`sizeof` gives the size of the variable, not the size of the object that you're pointing to (if there is one.) `sizeof(arrayVar)` will return the array size in bytes if and only if `arrayVar` is declared in scope as an array and not a pointer.

For example:

```
char myArray[10];
char* myPtr = myArray;

printf("%d\n", sizeof(myArray)) // prints 10 
printf("%d\n", sizeof(myPtr)); // prints 4 (on a 32-bit machine)
```

Comment: can you elaborate why the top one gives 10? is that in the stack or heap?

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's in the stack or on the heap (although, to be on the heap, it would have to be embedded in a `struct` definition.) The key is that the variable `myArray` is declared as an *array*, not as a *pointer*. So, the compiler sees that an array of 10 characters are declared, and allocates 10 bytes of storage to hold those 10 characters.

Comment: In the case of `myPtr`, all the compiler sees is that a pointer is being declared; it allocates 4 bytes to hold `myPtr` (on a 32-bit machine), but does not allocate any storage for it to point to. Instead of having its own unique memory for storing data, `myPtr` starts out by pointing to the memory allocated for `myArray`.

Does that help?

Answer (score 4):

sizeof(Array) is looked up at compile time, not at run time.  The information is not stored.

Are you perhaps interested in implementing bounds checking?  If so, there are a number of different ways to go about that.