# Bit manipulation library for ANSI C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

Does anyone knows a good bit manipulation library for ANSI C?
What I basically need, is ability, like in [Jovial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JOVIAL) to set specific bits in a variable, something like

```
// I assume LSB has index of 0
int a = 0x123;
setBits(&a,2,5, 0xFF);
printf("0x%x"); // should be 0x13F

int a = 0x123;
printf("0x%x",getBits(&a,2,5)); // should be 0x4

char a[] = {0xCC, 0xBB};
char b[] = {0x11, 0x12};
copyBits(a,/*to=*/4,b,/*from=*/,4,/*lengthToCopy=*/8);
// Now a == {0x1C, 0xB2}
```

There's a similar library called [bitfile](http://michael.dipperstein.com/bitlibs/), but it doesn't seem to support direct memory manipulation. It only supports feeding bits to file streams.

It's not hard to write, but if there's something tested - I won't reinvent the wheel.

Maybe this library exists as a part of bigger library (`bzip2`, `gzip` are the usual suspects)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c Wrap the answers up in functions if you must.

Comment: @dmckee the answers there don't include the `copyBits` funtion. And wrapping things in functions is not a "must" generally speaking, but it is a must for well structured code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be the problem I was tackling in my question

[Algorithm for copying N bits at arbitrary position from one int to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283221/algorithm-for-copying-n-bits-at-arbitrary-position-from-one-int-to-another)

There are several different alternatives provided, with the fastest being the assembly solution by fnieto.

Answer (score 7):

I think is considered "too simple" for a library; most functions would only be a statement or two, which would make the overhead of calling a library function a bit more than typical C programmers tolerate. :)

That said, the always-excellent [glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/) has two of the more complicated bit-oriented functions: `g_bit_nth_lsf()` and `g_bit_nth_msf()`. These are used to find the index of the first bit set, searching from the lowest or the highest bit, respectively.

Comment: I just wrote it, and it took 15 lines of tricky code and much more unit tests. It took me quite a few hours to do that, and I don't see any gain with not providing a simple library for that.

Comment: Really?  `stdbool.h` is pretty simple.

Answer (score 3):

You will come a long way with the following macros:

```
#define SETBITS(mem, bits)      (mem) |= (bits)
#define CLEARBITS(mem, bits)    (mem) &= ~(bits)
#define BIN(b7,b6,b5,b4, b3,b2,b1,b0)                      \
(unsigned char)(                                           \
    ((b7)<<7) + ((b6)<<6) + ((b5)<<5) + ((b4)<<4) +        \
    ((b3)<<3) + ((b2)<<2) + ((b1)<<1) + ((b0)<<0)          \
)
```

Then you can write

```
int a = 0x123;
SETBITS(a, BIN(0,0,0,1, 1,1,1,0));
printf("0x%x", a); // should be 0x13F
```

Comment: Half a solution. You need a GETBIT macro as well. And a loop. I'll post mine in a few days.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe the [algorithms](http://www.jjj.de/fxt/) from the "FXT" book (link at the bottom of the page) will be useful.

Comment: Excellent resource for C. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 0):

I may be a bit late but I made [this](https://github.com/SmushyTaco/Get-Set-Bit/tree/main) simple bit manipulation library for C that might interest you.