# c++ sizeof( string )

Tags: c++, string

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   cout << "size of String " << sizeof( string );
        
   system("PAUSE");
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Output:

> size of String = 4

Does that mean that, since `sizeof(char) = 1 Byte (0 to 255)`, string can only hold `4` characters?

Comment: Where is "string" coming from?  Running the example code through a compiler would yield a compile error, as a number of things would be undefined.  (I can't imagine the size any but the most naive of 'string' implementations being only 4.)

Comment: @dash-tom-bang just edited to include my header files

Comment: sizeof calculates the size of a datatype, which is useful if you're doing dynamic allocation. I believe string.length or size is what you want.

Comment: @Kevin: Neither of those headers necessarily defines `string`. If you want `std::string`, then it comes from `<string>`. `cout` is from `<iostream>`, but it's in namespace `std`. Take a minute to get some code that compiles: nobody can answer your question until they know what `string` actually is in your program, all they can do is guess what you left out.

Comment: I should add: it wouldn't be surprising if `<iostream>` includes `<string>` for you, but it would be fairly surprising if it did a `using namespace std;` for you...

Comment: @dash-tom-bang: The length, capacity, and reference count could be stored on the heap along with the string data.  MFC `CString` is implemented like this.

Comment: Think about what you're asking. Do you *honestly believe* that strings can only hold four characters? I'm sure you don't. Please ask what's *really* on your mind.

Comment: @dan04 I don't know if I've ever seen that done, thanks for the reference.  (In MSVC 2008, sizeof(std::string) is 28, and I've handrolled some SSO strings in the past that are definitely larger than 4 bytes.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It isn't clear from your example what 'string' is. If you have:

```
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

then `string` is `std::string`, and `sizeof(std::string)` gives you the size of the class instance and its data members, not the length of the string. To get that, use:

```
string s;
cout << s.size();
```

Answer (score 20):

When `string` is defined as:

```
char *string;
```

`sizeof(string)` tells you the size of the pointer. 4 bytes (You're on a 32-bit machine.) You've allocated no memory yet to hold text. You want a 10-char string? string = malloc(10); Now string points to a 10-byte buffer you can put characters in.

`sizeof(*string)` will be 1. The size of what string is pointing to, a char.

If you instead did

```
char string[10];
```

`sizeof(string)` would be 10. It's a 10-char array.
`sizeof(*string)` would be 1 still.

It'd be worth looking up and understanding the __countof macro.

Update: oh, yeah, NOW include the headers :)  'string' is a class whose instances take up 4 bytes, that's all that means. Those 4 bytes could point to something far more useful, such as a memory area holding more than 4 characters.

You can do things like:

```
string s = "12345";
cout << "length of String " << s.length();
```

Answer (score 8):

I know a lot of people had answered your question, but here are some points:

1. It's not the size of the `string` or the capacity of the string, this value represents the structural size of the class `string`, which you can see by its implementation (and it can change from implementation to implementation) that is a simple pointer;
2. As the `sizeof(string)` is the size of the class structure, you'll get the size of the only internal pointer, that in your case is 4 bytes (because you are in a 32-bit machine, this can change from platform to platform too);
3. This pointer inside the `string` class, points to a memory buffer where the class will hold the real string data, this memory buffer is reallocated as needed, it can increase/decrease as you append/delete/create more string text;
4. If you want to get the real size of the string, you need to call the `size()` method from the class which will check the memory buffer string size (which isn't the same as the memory buffer size).

I think your problem is your conception of `sizeof`, see more information [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sizeof) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671790/how-does-sizeofarray-work) is some explanation on how it works.

Answer (score 8):

`sizeof(char)` is always 1 byte. A `byte` which we think is `8-bits need not be the case`. There are architectures where a BYTE is 32-bits, 24-bits and so on. The `sizeof` applied to any other type is in multiples of `sizeof(char)` which is `by definition 1`.

The next important thing to note is that C++ has three character types: `plain char, signed char and unsigned char`. A `plain char` is either `signed` or `unsigned`. So it is wrong to assume that char can have only values from 0 to 255. This is true only when a char is 8-bits, and `plain char` is `unsigned`.

Having said, that assuming that 'string' is `'std::namespace'`, `sizeof(string) == 4` means that the sizeof the `'std::string'` class is 4 bytes. It occupies 4 times the number of bytes that a `'char'` on that machine takes. `Note that signed T, unsigned T always have the same size`. It does not mean that the actual buffer of characters (which is called string in common parlance) is only 4 bytes. Inside the `'std::string'` class, there is a non static member pointer which is allocated dynamically to hold the input buffer. This can have as many elements as the system allows (C++ places no restriction on this length). But since the `'std::string'` class only holds the pointer to this potentially infite length buffer, the sizeof(std::string) always remains the same as sizeof pointer on the given architecture which on your system is 4.

Answer (score 5):

Not at all.  It means that the class's structure is that, it doesn't include the dynamic memory it can control.  std::string will expand dynamically to meet any required size.

```
s.max_size() // will give the true maximum size
s.capacity() // will tell you how much it can hold before resizing again
s.size() // tells you how much it currently holds
```

The 4 you get from `sizeof` is likely a pointer of some kind to the larger structure.  Although some optimizations on some platforms will use it as the actual string data until it grows larger than can fit.

Answer (score 4):

No, it means that the sizeof the class string is 4.

It does not mean that a string can be contained in 4 bytes of memory. Not at all. But you have to difference between dynamic memory, used to contain the `size` characters a string can be made of, and the memory occupied by the address of the first of those characters

Try to see it like this:

```
contents  --------> |h|e|l|l|o| |w|o|r|ld|\0|
```

sizeof 4 refers to the memory occupied by contents. What it contents? Just a pointer to (the address of ) the first character in the char array.

How many characters does a string can contain ? Ideally, a character per byte available in memory.

How many characters does a string actually have? Well, theres a member function called `size()` that will tell you just that

```
size_type size() const
```

See more on the [SGI](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/basic_string.html) page !

Comment: What does "sizeof the class String is 4" actually mean?

Comment: It's the size of member variables necessary for the string classes function.

Comment: It's the size of the `pointer` to the `class` String. Which in this case seems to be on a 32 bit integer.

Comment: @Kevin: It means that when you write `string foo`, it takes up four bytes on the stack. The actual characters of the string are not part of the string object itself; they're in dynamic memory that the string allocates as needed.

Comment: So what's the limit as to how many characters I can store in a string:

example string a = "aksldjfkljklj234kljk123;4jklj123kj4k;jsdkl;jfkjsdklfjsdfsdf" 

is legal?

Comment: Yep, that's legal though you'd be incarcerated for having a user read that.

Comment: @Ivo: That's not correct. It's the size of the instance, which happens to contain nothing more than a pointer to dynamic memory.

Answer (score 0):

A `string` object contains a *pointer* to a buffer on the heap that contains the actual string data.  (It can also contain other implementation-specific meta-information, but yours apparently doesn't.)  So you're getting the size of that pointer, not the size of the array it points to.

Comment: With GCC's implementation std::string consists of a single pointer into an overallocated struct that keeps size, capacity and buffer all together in the same continuous memory block. Probably not uncommon in some other implementations either.

Comment: Microsoft uses that approach for their `CString` class, but surprisingly not for their version of `std::string`.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use strings and can find out its length by string.length() function. look at the below code:

```
// Finding length of a string in C++

#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int count(string);

int main()
{
string str;
cout << "Enter a string: ";
getline(cin,str);
cout << "\nString: " << str << endl;
cout << count(str) << endl;

return 0;

}

int count(string s){
if(s == "")
  return 0;
if(s.length() == 1)
  return 1;
else
    return (s.length());

}
```

you can get the details from :
http://www.programmingtunes.com/finding-length-of-a-string-in-c/

Answer (score -1):

size() of string gives the number of elements in the string whereas sizeof() function on a string gives three extra bits. strlen() of a character array gives the number of elements + 1 (because of null char delimiter) and keep in mind size of char is 1 byte. sizeof() on a char array gives the size assigned to the array

```
string str="hello";
char arr[x]="hello";
cout<<str.size()<<endl<<sizeof(str)<<endl;
cout<<strlen(arr)<<endl<<sizeof(arr)<<endl;
```

output is 5 8 5 x

Comment: in this response, you are confusing bytes and bits, giving wrong information (strlen does not add 1).

Comment: As an empirical fact it does. I've run this code on all data types and stored the results.