# Getting invalid size of string

Tags: c++, string

When i try to check the size of string i get the value 28 when I use the function

```
std::cout<<sizeof(std::string);
```

isn't the size suppose to be 4 bytes on a 32 bit system?
I am using visual studio 2019

I thought that string is a pointer to a char that is why the size would be 4 bytes on 32 bit system.

Comment: ***isn't the size suppose to be 4 bytes on a 32 bit system?*** No its usually larger than that.  In addition some implementations have a short string optimization which make it even larger because the characters in this short string optimization are stored in the class directly.

Comment: *isn't the size suppose to be 4 bytes on a 32 bit system?* Why do you expect that?

Comment: why should it be 4 bytes ?!?

Comment: Maybe tell us _what_ system you are on. And even it's a bit pedantic, using `std::cout` 
 and `std::string` help to make absolutely clear what you mean.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629301/c-sizeof

Comment: with `using string = char[4];` you will have expected answer ;-)

Comment: i thought that string is a pointer to a char that is why the size would be 4 bytes on  32 bit system.

Comment: @HurrairahNasir "i thought that string is a pointer to a char" - well, that's where you are wrong.

Comment: `string` also holds book-keeping information, such as "how long is the string?" Just storing the length will be another another 4 or 8 bytes. Modern `string` implementations also risk throwing away a some memory by including storage for small strings in the `string` itself. This improves cache-friendliness and saves time allocating and managing a dynamic array a lot of the time.

Comment: @HurrairahNasir *i thought that string is a pointer to a char* -- [Doesn't look like a simple pointer to me](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> isn't the size suppose to be 4 bytes on a 32 bit system?

No. The size of a `std::string` is not defined by the language standard. It can vary across implementations and there is no requirement or guarantee of it being 4 bytes on a 32 bit system.

> Getting invalid size of string

28 bytes is not "invalid" nor is it out of the ordinary in any way.

> i thought that string is a pointer to a char

`std::string` is not a pointer. It is a class that implements a more complex data structure than that.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the compiler, the target word size and the version of the standard library.

On pre-C++11 systems, it was possible (and fairly common) for std::string to use Copy-on-Write (CoW) mechanisms. In this case I think implementations would just contain a pointer to a string implementation object.

Post C++11, CoW has been [forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12199710/legality-of-cow-stdstring-implementation-in-c11) and also the standard requires std::string::length() to be constant time. This latter requirement effectively obliges string implementations to contain at least a pointer and a length field. Add that the need for a 'reserved' field (since the `std::string` can have more memory reserved than is being used).

Here are a couple of good references on the subject of C++11 and later std::strings:

- [layout](https://eu90h.github.io/cpp-strings.html)
- [gcc version and small string optimization](https://shaharmike.com/cpp/std-string/)