# Need suggestion for determining array size in C in efficient way

Tags: c, arrays

In java, java script and others languages has array.length functions available for knowing array length for looping and others needs. And in C programming I'm using

```
sizeof()
```

operator for determining the array size or array length by following procedure:

```
  int array [] ={12, 3, 4, 6};

  for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)); i++) {
 // do sometings
}
```

i want to know is

```
  sizeof(array)/sizeof(int)
```

is efficient for finding array size?
Or if others efficient way is avaiable, please suggest me.

Comment: Yes, it's efficient; it's evaluated at compile time, so it's constant time. But this won't work for pointer arrays, which is the important part.

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/671790/how-does-sizeofarray-work

Comment: And also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37538/how-do-i-determine-the-size-of-my-array-in-c?rq=1

Comment: @WChargin While you're searching for duplicates, why not go ahead and actually mark this question as a duplicate?

Comment: Prove, with numbers in hand, that a particular place in your program is a performance bottleneck. Until then, any talk about efficiency is a waste of time.

Comment: The linked answers in this comment chain may be a bit outdated post-C99

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is extremely efficient because it is a construct resulting in a compile-time constant (except for C99 VLAs, see below).  You might want to use:

```
sizeof(array)/sizeof(array[0])
```

instead, so you can use it with other-than-int types.  Maybe wrap it in a macro (of course, all the usual caveats about caution when using macros would apply).

On update: for my original answer above, I wasn't thinking about VLAs in C99, where:

> If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant. (6.5.3.4/2)

The count of VLA array elements may only be determinable at run-time (and evaluation can itself have side-effects), so for a VLA it is not a purely compile-time construct.  In most well-formed cases, the code-level behavior for a VLA will be effectively the same.  For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define countof_array(arr)  (sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]))

int vlaSize(void)
{
  return 8;
}

int main(void)
{
   int fixed_array[9] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };
   int vla_array[vlaSize()];

   printf("Fixed array: size = %zu bytes, count = %zu elements\n", 
           sizeof(fixed_array), countof_array(fixed_array));
   printf("VLA array:   size = %zu bytes, count = %zu elements\n", 
           sizeof(vla_array), countof_array(vla_array));

   return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
$ gcc -Wall -std=c99 so-misc.c
$ ./a.out
Fixed array: size = 36 bytes, count = 9 elements
VLA array:   size = 32 bytes, count = 8 elements
```

On further edit, striking this part:

> *Caveat: It would not be difficult to intentionally create a case where the semantics of `countof_array` would effectively differ for a VLA [...]*

because after thinking about it more, I'm not sure if this is true.  Asking about this in a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28040792/c99-vla-size-determination-and-sizeof-operator).

In any case, it is still extremely efficient, because to create the VLA in the first place the compiler has to figure out how much space the VLA will take up.  So even if not a compile-time constant for a VLA, it is still the most efficient way possible to determine an array size.

Comment: @MattMcNabb Is there a run-time `sizeof` I'm not aware of?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I would love to see an example of this, if you know of any. The entire Internet (my former self included) insists that `sizeof` is a strictly compile-time construct.

Answer (score 1):

`sizeof` is a compile-time construct, meaning that its value is determined during compilation, so it is free at runtime.  The only "cost" at runtime of using `sizeof` will be to load a constant value, just as if you had hard-coded it.

In other words, the code you have is efficient.

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof` is evaluated based on static type information (at compile-time).

One exception is in the case of C99's [variable-length arrays (VLAs).](http://docs.cray.com/books/004-2179-001/html-004-2179-001/z893434830malz.html/)

C (since C99) provides both Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) and Flexible Array Members (FAMs). For a variable length array, sizeof does evaluate its parameter, so there is a (minimal) run-time cost -- roughly equivalent to `std::vector::size()` in C++. 
For all other types (including `structs` that include flexible array members), sizeof does not evaluate its operand, so there is no run-time cost (the same as in C++).

> For a `struct` with a flexible array member: "the size of the
>   structure shall be equal to the offset of the last element of an
>   otherwise identical structure that replaces the flexible array member
>   with an array of unspecified length." (C99, §6.7.2.1/16).

It therefore will cause no performance change from using a normal integer that equals the value.